# Does ergodicity imply aperiodicity?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

If a Markov chain is ergodic, does that imply that the period of that Markov Chain is 1? (I know that an irreducible, aperiodic markov chain implies ergodicity but I want to know if the reverse is implied.)

Comment: What is your definition of ergodic?

Comment: The Markov chain is said to be ergodic if for some n* ≥0, (P^n*)ij > 0 for all pairs of states i and j (including j=i).

Comment: So you can go between any two states in the markov chain in the same number of steps for some fixed number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Choose some state $x$. By ergodicity, there is an $n$ such that $p^n(x,y) > 0$ for all other states $y$. Pick some state $z$ for which $p(z, x) > 0$; then we have $p^{n+1}(x, x) \geq p^n(x, z) p(z, x) > 0$. Since $\gcd(n, n+1) = 1$, aperiodicity is implied.